# What is the difference between autoradiography and scintillation counting?

Tags: photons, electrons, radiation, radioactivity, isotopes

How are the two techniques different? To the best of my understanding, both autoradiography and scintillation counting both depend on the radioactive emission of electrons (or photons) interacting with the molecules in the vicinity of the sample to generate a detectable signal.

Would also be glad if I can get some references where I can read more.

Thanks! (And I wish you all a nice week ahead!)

Comment: This is outside my branch. But autoradiography used to be done with photographic emulsions (plates or film), so it produced images. Nowadays one could use electronic sensors with pixels. Scintillation counting - to me it does not automatically imply imaging, it could be just a technique to count the activity of sample averaged over the bulk volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto radiography is a subfield of radiography in which a sample (usually biological) is impregnated with a radioactive tracer and then placed in close proximity to a radiation detector.  The sample may be a thin section mounted on a slide.  The detector may be photographic film in close contact with the sample or a scintillation counter.  The radioactive nuclide may be given to a living biological specimen before sections are taken or applied directly to the sections.

Scintillation counting is a technology in which radiation (photons, electrons) enter a scintillation crystal such as sodium iodide, a plastic scintilator or a gaseous scintilator and produce light by interacting with the scintillation material.  The light is measured with photomultiplier tubes or solid state detectors to produce a signal which can be an image (e.g. scintillation or gamma camera) or a simple series of counts.

A good reference for scintillation counting in medicine as well as many related topics is “physics in nuclear medicine” by Cherry, Sorensen and Phelps.

Comment: Autoradiography was heavily used in metallurgy and semiconductor research in the 50's and 60's.